# eBay api - fetch all listed items

Tags: php, xml, rest, ebay-api

I need to fetch all items currently listed on our `ebay` account with API.

Currently I am using this call `GetMyeBaySelling` http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html

But the thing with that the call returns me only the "Active Item"
So if I have an item that has no more stock on it that item is then inactive, so the call don't return me that item.

I am searching online I can't find any where some one complaining that he can't fetch item that are inactive.

I also tried this call `GetSellingManagerInventory`
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSellingManagerInventory.html
but it does the same

So my question is how do people manage to fetch a list of all item that are currently listed on there `ebay` profile even if they are inactive.

Comment: The [link](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html) states: *"To return all the selling containers, set DetailLevel to ReturnAll."* Have you tried doing so? If not, can you please do so and then say which container those inactive items are in?

Comment: @hakre Thanks For the reply! But i just did try, and i try ed to control+f in the responce and i can't find the product in the responce. but on the website ebay in my account i can see the product.

Comment: Have you looked at TotalNumberOfEntries and TotalNumberOfPages in the response? It may be that there is more than one page of results available in which the product may appear. In that case you would have to make more requests to retrieve the other pages.

Comment: @DavidT.Sadler Yes I'm actually Looping thought Maximum of page to get the totalNumberOfEntries

Answer (score 1):

@Nicolas Racine

Have you tried this one?

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

Just asking.

Comment: I currently use GetSellerList to retrieve all of our active listings, but it is a bit unreliable. We have 58,000+ listings, so need to make the API request 291 times to obtain all the listing information. The problem is (I think) that items are ending and starting during the time it takes to make 291 API requests, so all listings are often not returned. Does anyone know of a better way (must be using an API) to obtain all of my own listings? Even when I have the <EndTimeTo> and <EndTimeFrom> identical for all 291 requests, it often still does not return all of our listings.